# Why are created all this .css and .map files at the time of compiling sass?

Tags: sass, terminal, bootstrap-5

As you can see I have a lib\css folder with one scss file where I imported bootstrap.scss and an index.css where my code scss is compiled. The compilations works, the issue is WHY all these other .css and .css.map files are created???

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple scss files and you don't want every file to be converted in CSS then create a folder named `scss`. In that folder create the main scss file named `style.scss` or whatever name you want and move your scss files in this folder. Now rename all scss files except `style.scss` by adding `_` at the start of the file name for example:

> `header.scss` will be `_header.scss`.

Now import every scss file in `style.scss`. A file named `_header.scss` will be imported in `style.scss` as follows:

```
@import "header";
```

Now watch your scss folder as follows:

```
sass --watch path/to/scss:CSS
```

This will compile your scss files from scss folder and make only one CSS file.

Comment: The thing is that I only have one SCSS file. And this css folder plenty of css files is created outside my "style" folder, that has only 3 files;  index.scss, index.css.map and index.css. Appreciate your answer. @Ankit Mishra

Comment: For one scss file watch it `sass --watch style.scss:style.css`. *.css.map these files are a map for browsers, telling it information about the source files. These files link your CSS code to scss code and they are useful for debugging purposes as well. If still have any doubt you can ask if not you can upvote the answer.

Comment: unexpected identifier :( I have installed node, sass, git and watch sass. And still not working

Comment: Please attach a snippet of the error for better understanding.